# Find the ranking for Concatenated rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with concatenated values within both rows, I am therefore uniquely retrieve ranking for each row in the tables.

**UPDATE** 
The other tables has been added to question

```
 NamesTable
 NID   |  Name | 
  1    |  Mu   |
  2    |  Ni   |
  3    | ices  |

 GroupTable
 GID   |   GName       |
  1    |  GroupA       |
  2    |  GroupB       |
  3    |  GroupC       |
```

MainTable

```
   | NID         |   Ages       |  Group   |    
   | 1           |  84          |    1     |
   | 2           |  64          |    1     |
   | 3           |  78          |    1     |
   | 1           |  63          |    2     |
   | 2           |  25          |    2     |
   | 3           |  87          |    2     |
   | 1           |  43          |    3     |
   | 2           |  62          |    3     |
   | 3           |  37          |    3     |
```

Now the first Name is equated to the first age in the table, I am able to equate them using php and foreach statements, Now the problem is with the ranking of the ages per each group. I am ranking the names uniquely on each row or group.

Results which is expected

```
     | Names         |   Ages       |  Group   |  Ranking   |   
     | Mu,Ni,ices    |  84,64,78    |    1     |  1,3,2     |
     | Mu,Ni,ices    |  63,25,87    |    2     |  2,3,1     |
     | Mu,Ni,ices    |  43,62,37    |    3     |  2,1,3     |
```

In my quest to solving this, I am using `GROUP_CONCAT`, and I have been able to come to this level in the below query

```
  SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(Names) NAMES,
            GROUP_CONCAT(Ages) AGES,
            GROUP_CONCAT(Group) GROUPS,
            GROUP_CONCAT(  FIND_IN_SET(Ages, (  
                                        SELECT 
                                             GROUP_CONCAT( Age ORDER BY Age DESC)
                                        FROM (
                                                SELECT 
                                                    GROUP_CONCAT(Ages ORDER BY Ages DESC ) Age
                                                FROM 
                                                      `MainTable` s


                                                    GROUP by `Group`
                                            ) s 
                                        )
                                       )) rank


                                            FROM
                                `MainTable` c

                                GROUP by `Group`
```

This actually gives me the below results.

```
     | Names         |   Ages       |  Group   |  Ranking   |   
     | 1,2,3         |  84,64,78    |    1     |  7,9,8     |
     | 1,2,3         |  63,25,87    |    2     |  5,6,4     |
     | 1,2,3         |  43,62,37    |    3     |  2,1,3     |
```

The only problem is that the ranking Values increase from 1 to 9 instead of ranking each row uniquely. Its there any idea that can help me cross over and fix this? I would be grateful for your help. Thanks

Comment: Fix your data structure!  That is not the SQL way to represent data.  If this table is created by other tables, then the work should be done on the underlying tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually don't represent the data with the values above but they are selected into a temporary table, I made it like that for simplicity and to make everyone understand.

Comment: . . You should ask another question and show the base tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated my question, I have added all the already existing tables to the question